# Finding a specific FPGA version of a USRP image file for an X310

Tags: usrp, uhd

I have an X310 that requires a previous FPGA version than what I have. Going to the Ettus image page https://files.ettus.com/binaries/images/ I cant determine which one can revert me to FPGA 35.
I have:
FW 6 FPGA 36
and need:
FW ? FPGA 35

Is there a decoder ring that I am missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually, UHD will figure all of that out for you. If you run

```
uhd_images_downloader
```

on the command line, it will download the right version for you (the one that matches the UHD version). Then, simply run

```
uhd_image_loader --args type=x300,addr=x.y.z.w
```

to burn it (don't forget to power-cycle).

If you run

```
uhd_images_downloader -l
```

it will show you the URLs it will use for downloading.